# Loop through and check condition from a list using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, foreach

I am trying to write the code in an efficient way and to achieve the following:

1. I have 4 properties in the object, but I will be validating only two properties. If ConditionOne is met, completely get rid of the loop setting the Description. If ConditionTwo is met, set the description into a list and keep validating next ConditionOne and ConditionTwo and so on...

Apologize, my code below is not correct to what I want above. I need guidance/help on correcting the below

```
public class Input
{
 List<string> Description { get; set;}
}



    IList<Notes> notes = GetNotes (input);


                decimal noteNumber = GetTotalNumber();
                List<string> channel = GetChannels();
                string status =   GetStatus();
                DateTime date = GetDate();

                foreach (var item in notes)
                {
                    if (noteNumber == item.ConditionOne)
                      input.Description = item.Description;
break;
                    if(noteNumber == item.ConditionTwo)
                      input.Description = item.Description 
                    continue with next item in Foreach list of rows
                }

     public class Notes
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string Description{ get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string ConditionOne{ get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string ConditionTwo{ get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string All { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: For condition 2, are you saying you want to add it to the `channel` `List<string>` instance?

Comment: @CamBruce: you got it right I think, I modified my question with my requirement above, please have a look

Comment: @mjwills: Thank you for your feedback, sure. But I wrote the psuedocode on Break and Continue lines, I dont know how to write it, thats what I am seeking help.

Comment: See answer. Using curly brackets will make this more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `break` to break out of a loop. There is no reason to use any Lambda expressions here. This is pretty simple. Adding correct indentation and using curly brackets will make it much easier to understand. See below.

```
foreach (var item in notes)
{
   if (noteNumber == decimal.Parse(item.ConditionOne, NumberStyles.Currency))
   {
      // condition one - break out of loop
      break;
   } 

   if(noteNumber == item.ConditionTwo)
   {
        // condition two. add description to list
       input.Description.Add(item.Description}
   } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Cam, thank you for your help, this is something I am expecting. One question. My ConditionOne is string. However, noteNumber is decimal. Can you help me with comparing the values from ConditionOne to decimal noteNumber? I reckon its just a parse or something, i dont know correct syntax. Also, I have noteNumber as Datetime, Bool int as well in multiple scenarios, so just a parsing for these types would be of great help please.

Comment: To rephrase my question, is it better to convert left side decimal to string or convert rightside string to decimal? But I have different data types in left side in multiple scenarios. However right side its all string always. What's your opinion?

Comment: I also found that, one of the string value in ConditionOne is having $2000 (From the database) for example. Now I want to compare it to decimal value in the code as above which is in the left side. How to remove that dollar (Maybe substring or something? )and compare only numbers

Comment: Yes, the two values would need to be the same types. Preferably it would be the native format, such as `decimal` or `DateTime`

Comment: String.Replace() will do the job for you, try to google out first cause these are basic questions, i.e: how to replace a char in a string , or how to replace a substring in a string

Comment: Also there are parser for most data types , for converting string to int is Int.Parse(string s)

Comment: No, you dont' want to use `string.Replace()`. Simply use `decimal.Parse(item.ConditionOne, NumberStyles.Currency)` to get a currency into a decimal. Updated my answer

Comment: @CamBruce: Your answer is perfectly very close and helping me a lot. Only concern is, conversions. As I said, the right side is from database which is all string column. That column contains "$200" for example. Also it contains a list of int for another row like "123, 345" ...So Its actually not a currency column. How do I do?

Comment: Is there any metadata that distinguishes the differences between the different types of data so you can decide how to parse?

Comment: @CamBruce: Nope. Ok I can in the front end, change the decimal to int. How to still parse that string in rightside "$200" to int? Remember, "$200" is the string and not currency datatype. Also, the datetime to datetime value how to compare?

Comment: Yes, to parse a string value "$200" you can use the `decimal.Parse("$200", NumberStyles.Currency); `int` has a similar parsing method, but i would stay with `decimal` if you are dealing with currency.

Comment: for `DateTime` use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`, depending on the format of your dates.

Comment: @CamBruce: Thank you. Now I realize that you have put for noteNumber. I want this loop to cater to channel and status too and also datetime  (I updated my question with datetime method in the front now. Can you please help me. That would solve all my problem

Comment: @CamBruce: Thank you sorry for bugging you. I created new question for that :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138543/modify-foreach-to-efficiently-cater-for-various-datatypes

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure below snip make sense from execution/result point of view what you trying to achieve.

```
if(noteNumber == item.ConditionTwo)
                  input.Description = item.Description 
                continue with next item in Foreach list of rows
```

But I tried a solution as below for your problem using Linq.

```
var conditionOneDescription = notes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ConditionOne == noteNumber);
if(conditionOneDescription!=null)
// set the description 
input.Description = conditionOneDescription.Description
return;

// keep setting the input.Description if the second condition is met    
notes.Where(n => n.ConditionTwo == noteNumber).ToList().ForEach(n => input.Description = n.Description);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Learner, I have no idea who and how I got a downvote for my answer. It's more of a discouraging form of actions.

Comment: I will give an upvote, yours is quite useful too. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: No problem RSF. Can you help me on how to convert a database string column that has a value "$200" to a decimal? for comparision.

Comment: @Learner, 
try
`decimal amount = 0M;
decimal.TryParse(<your_db_string_value>.Replace("$", ""), out amount);`

Comment: RSF, thank you so much. I have multiple data types in left hand side but right side all string. How to do it efficiently in foreach. Cam is only doing for one scenario of converting to decimal. But my other variables in left are of different types. i am afraid I dont know how to change his foreach to satisfy various conditions. Like generics

Comment: @Learner, have a look at this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138367/how-to-convert-a-string-to-decimal-with-string-value-containing-amount-like-233